# How to store images from sdcard in avd to database in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to Android. I have just created an AVD with 256 MB android-SDcard in it in Android 2.1.  And I have inserted two images into it.  I have done this using the DDMS perspective.  And the images are now stored into a folder 100ANDRO in the DCIM folder of SDcard.  Now I want to create an application that allows the user to select the images through browsing the folders and need to save the corresponding image to the database android-sqlite.

Can someone help me to find an appropriate method for this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one method for this.

I have created a button for UPLOAD and on the click action I have set like this.

```
    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);

        }
    });
```

And I have overrided this method along with the same class as below.

```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
     {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
      {
        Uri photoUri = data.getData();
        if (photoUri != null)
        {
        try {
              String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
              Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null); 
         cursor.moveToFirst();
     int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
     String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
     cursor.close();
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
     imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     int size = bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight();
     ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(size);
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
     try {
     out.flush();
     out.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();}
     String bb = out.toString();
     byte[] x = out.toByteArray();
     image_value.setTag(x);
     image_value.setText(filePath);
     }catch(Exception e)
      {}
      }
    }
    }
```

Here image_value represents a hidden text view in the xml file.
I have passed the value of the image location and bytes as text view's value and tag.
And later on I have saved this bytes into the database for later display. Its working fine.

Thanks to all.